# Storing json as variable for reuse within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

I am learning jQuery and I would like to find out how to re-use ajax json data without having to make a second request.

e.g.

Categories Select Box:

```
<select id="Categories">
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
</select>
```

When the Category is changed using `jQuery("#Categories").change(function(){...`, an ajax call get request pulls the following ajax data.

```
[{"Id":"1","Item":"Apples","PricePerKilo":"10.00"},
 {"Id":"3","Item":"Oranges","PricePerKilo":"12.00"}]
```

And then the Products select box is updated as follows:

```
<select id="Products">
     <option value="1">Apples</option>
     <option value="3">Oranges</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want to do, is have an input box for the required weight. That way, when the value of the input #weight is changed, a total label will also get updated with the price.

```
jQuery('#weight').bind('input', function() { 
   jQuery("#total").text( "£ " + (jQuery('#weight').val() * SOMETHING ).toFixed(2) ); 
)};
```

Note the SOMETHING... This should be something like...

```
data.PricePerKilo WHERE data.Id = jQuery("#products").val();
```

Any ideas on how to make the json data reusable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can associate arbitrary data with a DOM element with [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Use the following to store it, after fetching the JSON:

```
jQuery("#products").data('productData', myData);
```

Then retrieve it with this:

```
var myData = jQuery("#products").data('productData');
```