# Reuse of JSON data populated by $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have a code like following:

```
$.getJSON("jsonlesson.txt", function(json) {
    console.log("success");
    $.each(json.lessonjson, function(key1, val1) {
        $("#lessonid").append("<option value='" + val1.lessonkey + "'>" + val1.lessonval + "</option>");
    });
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("second success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
})
.error(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Is it possible to re-use of JSON data populated by $.getJSON?

Should I be able to write code like following?

```
lessonArray = jQuery.grep(json.lessonjson, function(product, i) {
            return product.subjectkey == selectedsubject;
```

How to re-use the `JOSN` data for `grep` in another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```js
$.getJSON('jsonlesson.txt', function (json) {
  console.log('success');
  lessonArray = json.lessonjson;

  //where this lessonArray is global variable.
  $.each(json.lessonjson, function (key1, val1) {
    $('#lessonid').append("<option value='" + val1.lessonkey + "'>" + val1.lessonval + '</option>');
  });
})
  .done(function () {
    console.log('second success');
  })
  .fail(function () {
    console.log('error');
  })
  .always(function () {
    console.log('complete');
  })
  .error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Then you can use that `lessonArray` variable all over the page.

Comment: @SwarupModak Happy to help you :-). mark it answer or upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the data with a jQuery.JSON call, save the queried data before using them within an internal function.

```
jQuery("#DOMdata").data(' element, key, value);
```

Then retrieve it with this:

```
var myData = jQuery("#DOMdata").data(key);
```

[storing json as variable for reuse within another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258693/storing-json-as-variable-for-reuse-within-another-function)